# Normality of a blow up

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

Let $X$ be a quasi-projective normal $\mathbb C$-variety and $Y\subset X$ a smooth subvariety such that $X$ is normally flat along $Y$ (i.e. the normal cone of $X$ along $Y$ is flat over $Y$).
Is the blow-up $Bl_Y(X)$ normal?

Comment: What do you mean by normally flat?

Comment: Thank you for your remark. I have included the definition in the question: it means that the normal cone of $X$ along $Y$ is flat over $Y$.

Comment: That is not true.  There are isolated normal surface singularities that are not “absolutely isolated “.

Comment: Thank you for your counter-example. Do you know, please what would be the answer if moreover the normal cone is assumed to be smooth?